# implementing list insert first in generic List

Tags: c, list

```
ListResult listInsertFirst(List list, ListElement element) {
    NULL_ARG(list, LIST_NULL_ARGUMENT);
    Node first = elementCopy(list, element);
    NULL_ARG(first, LIST_OUT_OF_MEMORY);
    if(!list->size){
        list->iterator = first;
        list->last = first;
    }
    first->next = list->first;
    list->first = first;
    list->size++;
    return LIST_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is my code for list insert first but it give me an error "segmentation fault" when I run it in Eclipse Indigo. I've tried to erase this line:

```
list->first = first;
```

and it didn't give me the error.

The function `elementCopy` works perfectly: Creates new node with the data element and set the next to `NULL`.

```
Node elementCopy(List list, ListElement e){
    Node tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp));
    NULL_ARG(tmp, NULL);
    tmp->data = list->copyElement(e);
    NULL_ARG(tmp->data, NULL);
    tmp->next = NULL;
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: Is this `C`? On witch line segfault happens? How does `elementCopy` function look like? you might waat to retag your question so that it gets attention from the right SO-users... and o need for caps...

Comment: Is `NULL_ARG()` actually a macro for "ASSERT(arg != NULL)"?  Confusing.

Comment: yes it checks if it is NULL and return LIST_NULL_ARGUMENT